# "This information is required of you" or "this information is required from you"?

Tags: prepositions

Can you please tell if I need to say *required of* or *required from* in the context below?

> This information is **required of** you for use to be able to prepare quotes.
>
> This information is **required from** you for use to be able to prepare quotes.

I'd also like to know other contexts where you would use one rather than the other.

Comment: You could simplify the wordy sentence: "The information is needed to prepare quotes." (Using *required* is very dictatorial). It also shifts the focus from "what you are required to do" to "what we need".

Comment: "for use to be able" is ungrammatical

Comment: Do you mean "for users"?

Answer (score 1):

*required from* works better here; we use this construction when the focus is on results, things, or end products.

We use *required of* to focus on the manner of doing certain thing or the behaviour of a person.

Your examples are ungrammatical and verbose, as commented.  I suggest the following:

> This information is required **from** you to prepare quotes.